# XeLaTeX prohibits cropping to eps limits

Tags: xetex, eps, includegraphics

Compiling the following mwe.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,8pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \fbox{\includegraphics[clip,trim=
    0
    0
    2363
    4136,
    width=\textwidth]{mwe}} \\ %
\end{document}
```

with the subsequent mwe.eps results in a

**Package graphics Error: Division by 0.**

Does anyone know why?

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Creator: cairo 1.15.6 (http://cairographics.org)
%%CreationDate: Fri Apr 06 16:57:41 2018
%%Pages: 1
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 2363 4136
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
save
50 dict begin
/q { gsave } bind def
/Q { grestore } bind def
/cm { 6 array astore concat } bind def
/w { setlinewidth } bind def
/J { setlinecap } bind def
/j { setlinejoin } bind def
/M { setmiterlimit } bind def
/d { setdash } bind def
/m { moveto } bind def
/l { lineto } bind def
/c { curveto } bind def
/h { closepath } bind def
/re { exch dup neg 3 1 roll 5 3 roll moveto 0 rlineto
      0 exch rlineto 0 rlineto closepath } bind def
/S { stroke } bind def
/f { fill } bind def
/f* { eofill } bind def
/n { newpath } bind def
/W { clip } bind def
/W* { eoclip } bind def
/BT { } bind def
/ET { } bind def
/pdfmark where { pop globaldict /?pdfmark /exec load put }
    { globaldict begin /?pdfmark /pop load def /pdfmark
    /cleartomark load def end } ifelse
/BDC { mark 3 1 roll /BDC pdfmark } bind def
/EMC { mark /EMC pdfmark } bind def
/cairo_store_point { /cairo_point_y exch def /cairo_point_x exch def } def
/Tj { show currentpoint cairo_store_point } bind def
/TJ {
  {
    dup
    type /stringtype eq
    { show } { -0.001 mul 0 cairo_font_matrix dtransform rmoveto } ifelse
  } forall
  currentpoint cairo_store_point
} bind def
/cairo_selectfont { cairo_font_matrix aload pop pop pop 0 0 6 array astore
    cairo_font exch selectfont cairo_point_x cairo_point_y moveto } bind def
/Tf { pop /cairo_font exch def /cairo_font_matrix where
      { pop cairo_selectfont } if } bind def
/Td { matrix translate cairo_font_matrix matrix concatmatrix dup
      /cairo_font_matrix exch def dup 4 get exch 5 get cairo_store_point
      /cairo_font where { pop cairo_selectfont } if } bind def
/Tm { 2 copy 8 2 roll 6 array astore /cairo_font_matrix exch def
      cairo_store_point /cairo_font where { pop cairo_selectfont } if } bind def
/g { setgray } bind def
/rg { setrgbcolor } bind def
/d1 { setcachedevice } bind def
/cairo_flush_ascii85_file { cairo_ascii85_file status { cairo_ascii85_file flushfile } if } def
/cairo_image { image cairo_flush_ascii85_file } def
/cairo_imagemask { imagemask cairo_flush_ascii85_file } def
%%EndProlog
%%BeginSetup
%%EndSetup
%%Page: 1 1
%%BeginPageSetup
%%PageBoundingBox: 0 0 2363 4136
%%EndPageSetup
q 0 0 2363 4136 rectclip
1 0 0 -1 0 4136 cm q
0 g
2298.25 2766.617 m 2298.25 2767.32 l 2299.207 2767.32 l 2299.207 2767.441
 l 2299.449 2767.441 l 2299.574 2767.57 l 2299.688 2767.688 l 2299.809 2767.688
 l 2299.809 2767.816 l 2299.93 2768.047 l 2299.93 2768.523 l 2300.051 2769.969
 l 2300.168 2769.844 l 2300.168 2769.719 l 2300.289 2769.617 l 2300.414 
2769.492 l 2300.414 2769.121 l 2300.527 2769.012 l 2300.527 2767.816 l 2300.414
 2767.688 l 2300.414 2767.57 l 2300.289 2767.441 l 2300.289 2767.32 l 2300.168
 2767.219 l 2300.051 2767.094 l 2299.809 2766.844 l 2299.688 2766.844 l 
2299.574 2766.723 l 2299.207 2766.723 l 2299.09 2766.617 l 2298.488 2766.617
 l f*
0.480002 w
1 J
1 j
[] 0.0 d
10 M q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
1953.605 -104.527 m 1953.484 -104.527 l 722.164 -3490.207 m 722.164 -3470.527
 l 726.367 -3490.207 m 726.367 -3470.527 l 730.445 -3490.207 m 730.445 -3470.527
 l 734.527 -3490.207 m 734.527 -3470.527 l 722.164 -3470.527 m 738.727 -3470.527
 l S Q
0.72 w
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
0.363 -69.004 m 0.363 -4135.332 l 2362.57 -4135.332 m 2362.57 -69.004 l
 61.926 -15.363 m 61.926 -4073.785 l 2321.527 -4094.309 m 2321.527 -15.363
 l 41.406 -15.363 m 41.406 -4094.309 l 0.363 -4135.332 m 2362.57 -4135.332
 l 0.363 -4094.309 m 2321.527 -4094.309 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
2211.246 -4087.684 m 2200.566 -4087.684 l 2206.57 -4084.074 l 2200.566 
-4080.496 l 2211.246 -4080.496 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
2090.289 -4084.074 m 2090.289 -4073.785 l S Q
0.720003 w
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
1969.328 -4086.5 m 1980.125 -4086.5 l 1980.125 -4081.68 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
1859.168 -4084.074 m 1859.168 -4073.785 l 1748.891 -4086.613 m 1738.086
 -4086.613 l 1738.086 -4080.605 m 1744.684 -4086.613 l 1742.164 -4084.328
 m 1748.891 -4080.496 l 1627.93 -4084.074 m 1627.93 -4073.785 l 1517.766
 -4086.133 m 1517.766 -4084.949 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
1517.645 -4084.922 m 1517.531 -4084.074 l 1516.926 -4083.371 l 1516.207
 -4082.777 l 1515.367 -4082.637 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
1515.363 -4082.551 m 1506.965 -4082.551 l 1396.684 -4084.074 m 1396.684
 -4073.785 l 1286.523 -4087.094 m 1275.727 -4087.094 l 1280.523 -4087.094
 m 1280.523 -4081.113 l 1275.727 -4081.113 m 1286.523 -4081.113 l 1165.563
 -4084.074 m 1165.563 -4073.785 l S Q
0.72 w
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
1049.406 -4082.523 m 1049.406 -4080.719 l 1055.289 -4080.719 l 1055.289
 -4083.738 l S Q
0.720003 w
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
1052.402 -4086.613 m 1053.484 -4086.387 l 1054.449 -4085.766 l 1055.047
 -4084.809 l 1055.285 -4083.738 l S Q
0.72 w
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
1052.414 -4086.727 m 1047.609 -4086.727 l S Q
0.720003 w
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
1044.723 -4083.738 m 1044.965 -4084.809 l 1045.57 -4085.766 l 1046.523 
-4086.387 l 1047.609 -4086.613 l S Q
0.72 w
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
1044.609 -4083.738 m 1044.609 -4080.719 l 934.328 -4084.074 m 934.328 -4073.785
 l S Q
0.720003 w
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
824.164 -4086.5 m 813.363 -4086.5 l 813.363 -4081.68 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
818.164 -4086.5 m 818.164 -4081.68 l 703.203 -4084.102 m 703.203 -4073.758
 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
592.922 -4081.68 m 592.922 -4086.5 l 582.121 -4086.5 l 582.121 -4081.68
 l S Q
0.72 w
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
586.93 -4082.891 m 586.93 -4086.5 l 471.973 -4084.074 m 471.973 -4073.758
 l 361.809 -4087.43 m 361.809 -4084.695 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
361.688 -4084.695 m 361.566 -4083.738 l 361.086 -4082.75 l 360.371 -4082.047
 l 359.406 -4081.566 l 358.445 -4081.453 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
358.453 -4081.453 m 354.25 -4081.453 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
354.246 -4081.453 m 353.285 -4081.566 l 352.328 -4082.047 l 351.605 -4082.75
 l 351.125 -4083.738 l 351.004 -4084.695 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
351.008 -4084.695 m 351.008 -4087.43 l 361.809 -4087.43 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
240.734 -4084.074 m 240.734 -4073.785 l 130.57 -4081.34 m 130.57 -4083.484
 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
127.93 -4086.133 m 128.891 -4085.879 l 129.852 -4085.398 l 130.328 -4084.441
 l 130.566 -4083.484 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
127.93 -4086.133 m 122.527 -4086.133 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
119.891 -4083.484 m 120.129 -4084.441 l 120.609 -4085.398 l 121.57 -4085.879
 l 122.527 -4086.133 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
119.77 -4083.484 m 119.77 -4081.34 l 9.609 -4084.074 m 9.609 -4073.785 
l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
17.043 -3963.125 m 6.242 -3963.125 l 8.645 -3965.52 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
21.969 -3854.297 m 11.648 -3854.297 l S Q
0.720003 w
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
6.367 -3744.398 m 6.602 -3745.328 l 7.195 -3746.176 l 8.164 -3746.652 l
 S Q
0.72 w
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
9.859 -3742.34 m 8.887 -3741.945 l 7.918 -3742.086 l 7.094 -3742.566 l 
6.598 -3743.27 l 6.359 -3744.258 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
9.965 -3742.34 m 17.047 -3746.766 l 17.047 -3741.973 l S Q
0.720003 w
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
21.965 -3633.965 m 11.641 -3633.965 l 6.25 -3526.461 m 6.25 -3524.039 l
 S Q
0.72 w
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
10.926 -3524.039 m 10.813 -3523.191 l 10.211 -3522.488 l 9.477 -3521.895
 l 8.652 -3521.781 l 7.805 -3521.895 l 7.094 -3522.488 l 6.496 -3523.191
 l 6.359 -3524.039 l S Q
0.720003 w
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
11.035 -3524.066 m 11.035 -3525.25 l S Q
0.72 w
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
13.441 -3521.781 m 12.594 -3521.895 l 11.883 -3522.488 l 11.281 -3523.191
 l 11.168 -3524.039 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
13.457 -3521.754 m 14.637 -3521.754 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
16.914 -3524.039 m 16.805 -3523.191 l 16.203 -3522.488 l 15.492 -3521.895
 l 14.645 -3521.781 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
17.055 -3524.039 m 17.055 -3526.434 l 21.957 -3413.773 m 11.641 -3413.773
 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
6.25 -3304.211 m 14.645 -3306.609 l 14.645 -3300.602 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
12.262 -3302.406 m 17.051 -3302.406 l 21.965 -3193.438 m 11.656 -3193.438
 l 17.051 -3086.051 m 17.051 -3083.625 l S Q
0.720003 w
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
16.918 -3083.652 m 16.801 -3082.809 l 16.195 -3082.074 l 15.473 -3081.512
 l 14.652 -3081.371 l S Q
0.72 w
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
14.656 -3081.258 m 13.445 -3081.258 l S Q
0.720003 w
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
13.438 -3081.371 m 12.594 -3081.512 l 11.871 -3082.074 l 11.289 -3082.809
 l 11.164 -3083.652 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
11.035 -3083.652 m 11.035 -3086.051 l 6.238 -3086.051 l 6.238 -3081.848
 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
21.965 -2973.246 m 11.633 -2973.246 l S Q
0.72 w
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
46.449 -2861.77 m 47.16 -2863.207 l 48.254 -2864.277 l 49.57 -2865.012 
l 51.133 -2865.379 l S Q
0.720003 w
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
51.125 -2865.492 m 54.719 -2865.492 l S Q
0.72 w
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
54.727 -2865.379 m 55.563 -2865.238 l 56.293 -2864.645 l 56.895 -2863.914
 l 57.008 -2863.094 l 56.895 -2862.25 l 56.293 -2861.516 l 55.563 -2860.926
 l 54.727 -2860.813 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
54.719 -2860.699 m 53.539 -2860.699 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
53.406 -2860.699 m 52.57 -2860.813 l 51.73 -2861.289 l 51.242 -2862.137
 l 51.133 -2862.98 l S Q
0.720003 w
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
51.125 -2863.094 m 51.125 -2865.492 l 61.918 -2752.93 m 51.727 -2752.93
 l S Q
0.72 w
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
17.051 -2642.891 m 6.246 -2640.488 l 6.246 -2645.281 l 7.445 -2645.281 
l S Q
0.719997 w
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
21.984 -2532.715 m 11.656 -2532.715 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
8.656 -2420.277 m 7.805 -2420.406 l 7.09 -2420.883 l 6.609 -2421.602 l 
6.375 -2422.328 l 6.484 -2423.168 l 6.855 -2423.883 l 7.445 -2424.488 l 
8.289 -2424.844 l 9.016 -2424.844 l 9.852 -2424.488 l 10.457 -2423.883 l
 10.816 -2423.168 l 10.926 -2422.328 l 10.691 -2421.602 l 10.211 -2420.883
 l 9.496 -2420.406 l h
8.656 -2420.277 m S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
13.457 -2420.277 m 12.617 -2420.406 l 11.887 -2421.008 l 11.297 -2421.723
 l 11.172 -2422.563 l 11.297 -2423.398 l 11.887 -2424.125 l 12.617 -2424.719
 l 13.457 -2424.844 l S Q
0.720003 w
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
13.438 -2420.184 m 14.641 -2420.184 l S Q
0.719997 w
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
14.652 -2424.844 m 15.492 -2424.719 l 16.203 -2424.125 l 16.809 -2423.398
 l 16.934 -2422.563 l 16.809 -2421.723 l 16.203 -2421.008 l 15.492 -2420.406
 l 14.652 -2420.277 l S Q
0.720003 w
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
14.637 -2424.969 m 13.441 -2424.969 l 21.969 -2312.543 m 11.641 -2312.543
 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
16.918 -2203.82 m 16.309 -2202.617 l 15.484 -2201.66 l 14.398 -2200.82 
l 13.195 -2200.344 l 11.879 -2200.211 l S Q
0.72 w
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
11.883 -2200.09 m 8.648 -2200.09 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
8.648 -2200.211 m 7.805 -2200.324 l 7.094 -2200.934 l 6.484 -2201.648 l
 6.367 -2202.492 l 6.484 -2203.332 l 7.094 -2204.043 l 7.805 -2204.648 l
 8.648 -2204.77 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
8.648 -2204.891 m 9.859 -2204.891 l S Q
0.719997 w
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
9.859 -2204.758 m 10.699 -2204.641 l 11.422 -2204.043 l 12.016 -2203.32
 l 12.129 -2202.477 l S Q
0.72 w
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
12.242 -2202.48 m 12.242 -2200.09 l 21.965 -2092.199 m 11.648 -2092.199
 l 2321.527 -15.363 m 41.406 -15.363 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
17.055 -1985.164 m 6.25 -1985.164 l 8.648 -1987.445 l S Q
0.719997 w
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
6.859 -1980.238 m 8.656 -1980.961 l 10.703 -1981.438 l 12.621 -1981.438
 l 14.652 -1980.961 l 16.457 -1980.238 l S Q
0.72 w
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
6.965 -1977.969 m 6.484 -1978.574 l 6.367 -1979.168 l 6.484 -1979.766 l
 6.965 -1980.379 l S Q
0.719997 w
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
16.457 -1977.957 m 14.652 -1977.242 l 12.621 -1976.766 l 10.703 -1976.766
 l 8.656 -1977.242 l 6.859 -1977.957 l S Q
0.720003 w
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
16.441 -1980.375 m 16.918 -1979.777 l 17.035 -1979.176 l 16.918 -1978.578
 l 16.441 -1977.973 l S Q
0.72 w
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
21.965 -1872.004 m 11.648 -1872.004 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
17.055 -1763.637 m 6.25 -1763.637 l 8.648 -1766.047 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
17.055 -1757.645 m 6.25 -1757.645 l 8.648 -1760.039 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
21.965 -1651.688 m 11.648 -1651.688 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
17.055 -1545 m 6.25 -1545 l 8.648 -1547.41 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
6.367 -1539.012 m 6.617 -1539.969 l 7.211 -1540.809 l 8.168 -1541.293 l
 S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
9.859 -1537.094 m 8.898 -1536.734 l 7.926 -1536.848 l 7.094 -1537.324 l
 6.617 -1538.051 l 6.367 -1539.012 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
9.969 -1536.969 m 17.043 -1541.406 l 17.043 -1536.605 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
21.965 -1431.496 m 11.648 -1431.496 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
17.055 -1324.566 m 6.25 -1324.566 l 8.648 -1326.965 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
6.25 -1320.965 m 6.25 -1318.563 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
10.93 -1318.566 m 10.813 -1317.727 l 10.203 -1317.008 l 9.496 -1316.406
 l 8.648 -1316.293 l 7.805 -1316.406 l 7.094 -1317.008 l 6.484 -1317.727
 l 6.367 -1318.566 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
11.043 -1318.566 m 11.043 -1319.766 l S Q
0.720003 w
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
13.438 -1316.297 m 12.594 -1316.414 l 11.887 -1317.012 l 11.277 -1317.734
 l 11.16 -1318.578 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
13.441 -1316.176 m 14.645 -1316.176 l S Q
0.72 w
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
16.934 -1318.563 m 16.801 -1317.727 l 16.211 -1317.008 l 15.484 -1316.406
 l 14.652 -1316.293 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
17.055 -1318.566 m 17.055 -1320.969 l 21.965 -1211.285 m 11.648 -1211.285
 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
17.055 -1104.727 m 6.25 -1104.727 l 8.648 -1107.121 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
6.25 -1098.723 m 14.645 -1101.121 l 14.645 -1095.121 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
12.242 -1096.926 m 17.055 -1096.926 l 21.965 -990.965 m 11.648 -990.965
 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
17.055 -884.047 m 6.25 -884.047 l 8.648 -886.441 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
17.043 -880.57 m 17.043 -878.168 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
16.934 -878.168 m 16.801 -877.328 l 16.211 -876.609 l 15.484 -876.012 l
 14.652 -875.891 l S Q
0.720003 w
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
14.645 -875.77 m 13.441 -875.77 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
13.438 -875.891 m 12.594 -876.012 l 11.887 -876.609 l 11.277 -877.332 l
 11.16 -878.176 l S Q
0.72 w
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
11.059 -878.168 m 11.059 -880.563 l 6.25 -880.563 l 6.25 -876.367 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
21.965 -770.766 m 11.648 -770.766 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
17.055 -443.406 m 6.25 -443.406 l 8.648 -445.805 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
17.055 -437.402 m 6.25 -435.004 l 6.25 -439.805 l 7.457 -439.805 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
17.055 -663.844 m 6.25 -663.844 l 8.648 -666.242 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
6.367 -656.648 m 7.094 -658.086 l 8.168 -659.172 l 9.496 -659.891 l 11.043
 -660.246 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
11.043 -660.367 m 14.637 -660.367 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
14.652 -660.246 m 15.484 -660.125 l 16.211 -659.527 l 16.801 -658.805 l
 16.934 -657.965 l 16.801 -657.125 l 16.211 -656.406 l 15.484 -655.809 l
 14.652 -655.688 l S Q
0.720003 w
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
14.645 -655.566 m 13.441 -655.566 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
13.438 -655.574 m 12.594 -655.695 l 11.754 -656.172 l 11.277 -657.008 l
 11.16 -657.855 l S Q
0.72 w
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
11.043 -657.965 m 11.043 -660.367 l 21.969 -550.449 m 11.637 -550.449 l
 21.969 -330.246 m 11.637 -330.246 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
17.055 -223.082 m 6.25 -223.082 l 8.648 -225.484 l S Q
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
8.648 -214.809 m 7.805 -214.93 l 7.094 -215.406 l 6.617 -216.133 l 6.367
 -216.848 l 6.484 -217.688 l 6.852 -218.406 l 7.445 -219.008 l 8.289 -219.367
 l 9.012 -219.367 l 9.859 -219.008 l 10.449 -218.406 l 10.813 -217.688 l
 10.93 -216.848 l 10.699 -216.133 l 10.203 -215.406 l 9.496 -214.93 l h
8.648 -214.809 m S Q
0.720003 w
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
13.438 -214.809 m 12.594 -214.93 l 11.887 -215.527 l 11.277 -216.254 l 
11.16 -217.09 l 11.277 -217.93 l 11.887 -218.648 l 12.594 -219.254 l 13.438
 -219.367 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
13.441 -214.688 m 14.645 -214.688 l S Q
0.72 w
2 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
14.652 -219.363 m 15.484 -219.246 l 16.211 -218.645 l 16.801 -217.926 l
 16.934 -217.09 l 16.801 -216.246 l 16.211 -215.523 l 15.484 -214.926 l 
14.652 -214.805 l S Q
1 j
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
14.645 -219.488 m 13.441 -219.488 l 2321.527 -3389.781 m 2340.734 -3389.781
 l 2321.527 -2733.133 m 2340.734 -2733.133 l 2321.527 -2076.492 m 2340.734
 -2076.492 l 2321.527 -1419.844 m 2340.734 -1419.844 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
2322.609 -0.363 m 2322.609 -15.363 l 2342.414 -15.363 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
2322.609 -672.008 m 2341.809 -672.008 l S Q
0.479999 w
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
1983.973 -15.363 m 2137.934 -15.363 l S Q
0.72 w
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
2112.25 -200.047 m 2137.934 -200.047 l 2112.25 -261.609 m 2137.934 -261.609
 l 2112.25 -330.012 m 2137.934 -330.012 l 2112.25 -15.363 m 2322.609 -15.363
 l 2112.25 -104.289 m 2137.934 -104.289 l 2132.41 -81.004 m 2132.41 -79.684
 l S Q
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
2176.809 -613.93 m 2176.328 -613.93 l 2112.25 -617.293 m 2137.934 -617.293
 l 2112.25 -672.008 m 2322.609 -672.008 l 2274.73 -227.406 m 2274.73 -111.125
 l 2185.809 -672.008 m 2185.809 -15.363 l 2112.25 -15.363 m 2112.25 -672.008
 l 2137.934 -15.363 m 2137.934 -672.008 l 2322.609 -672.008 m 2322.609 -15.363
 l 2307.008 -589.57 m 2307.008 -588.25 l S Q
0.479999 w
q 1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
2112.25 -672.008 m 2005.332 -672.008 l 2089.449 -672.008 m 2089.449 -15.363
 l 2061.367 -672.008 m 2061.367 -15.363 l 2033.41 -672.008 m 2033.41 -15.363
 l 2005.332 -672.008 m 2005.332 -15.363 l 2112.25 -617.293 m 2005.332 -617.293
 l 2112.25 -578.891 m 2005.332 -578.891 l 2112.25 -360.848 m 2005.332 -360.848
 l 2112.25 -330.012 m 2005.332 -330.012 l 2112.25 -261.609 m 2005.332 -261.609
 l 2112.25 -200.047 m 2005.332 -200.047 l 2112.25 -104.289 m 2005.332 -104.289
 l S Q
Q Q
showpage
%%Trailer
end restore
%%EOF
```

Comment: BTW, neither class `article` nor package `graphicx` know an option `8pt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `trim` option cuts `4136` from the right, the same amount as the width of the bounding box. The same happens with the height, thus the size after trimming is 0 x 0. Then zero is scaled to `width=\textwidth` or the scale factor is `\textwidth` / 0, meaning division by zero.

Since option `clip` is also given, it is easier to remove the whole image:

```
\fbox{}
```

And the error is gone. (Also notice, `\\` without following text causes a "there is no line to end" error.)

Maybe, you want to use option `viewport` instead of `trim`. But it does not make sense with the same values as the bounding box.

The options are explained in ["Packages in the 'graphics' bundle"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf).